# Row deadlock when concurrently modifying different entities with hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, wildfly, deadlock

I'm using hibernate within an wdilfy 10 server and I am facing the following problem:

There is the parent entity `Parent`, that has a collection of `Child` entities and there is a job, that loads a cuple of `Parent` entities, clears the child-collection and puts new `Child` entities into it.

When this task is executed concurrently multiple times and even though each task is processing its own list of `Parent`entities, occasionally a deadlock occures and I don't understand how this can happen.

The MS-SQL server profiler shows, that there is a deadlock on a row of the `Child` entitiy table. But since no `Child` is shared between the `Parent`s and no `Parent` is processed by more than ond task, no row of the `Child` table should be accessed by more than one task at all.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Can you share some of the code that is relevant and the results from profiler maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Try using re-try logic. I usually re-try up to three times when I know that other process could possibly be locking some of the resources my code uses. If this doesn't help you, then you need to see the deadlock graph.

Get the deadlock graph in order to precisely locate the occurrence of the deadlock. You can get the deadlock graph from the SQL Server Profiler. Find the events Deadlock graph, Deadlock or Deadlock Chain in the Locks section.